# Replacing dots between letters [ORACLE]

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I have a string which contains dots.

```
select 'String.Cont.ains 123.FD DF.123 11.11' str from dual
```

I need to replace dots to dots with space, but only when a letter is before the dot and a letter is after the dot. In all other cases the dot must not be replaced.

Can I do this with `regexp_replace`?

Result must be like this :

```
String. Cont. ains 123.FD DF.123 11.11
```

I'm trying to use this:

```
select regexp_replace('String.Cont.ains 123.FD DF.123 11.11','(\.){1,}','. ')from dual
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
([a-z])(\.+)([a-z])
```

which looks for a character, one or more dots and then another character, and replace it with

```
\1\2 \3
```

i.e. the first character, the dots, a space, and the second character. In Oracle (note the use of the `i` flag so we don't have to specify `[A-Za-z]` instead of just `[a-z]`):

```
SELECT 
REGEXP_REPLACE('String.Cont.ains 123.FD DF.123 11.11', '([a-z])(\.+)([a-z])', '\1\2 \3', 1, 0, 'i') AS new
FROM dual
```

Output:

```
NEW
String. Cont. ains 123.FD DF.123 11.11
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a2c8d97087253fae2b6cb7d89a592fb4)